# Azure ServiceBus ConnectionsQuotaExceeded for namespace

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

We are using Azure ServiceBus in our project to pass messages to different components. Currently we have 7 topics and 45 subscriptions among those topics.
Recently we have started getting Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QuotaExceededException: ConnectionsQuotaExceeded for namespace.

According to [Azure ServiceBus Quotas and Limits](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-bus-quotas/) concurrent connections limit per namespace is 1000. We are definitely not going above 200. Is anyone having similar issue?

Below is the stack trace:

Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QuotaExceededException: ConnectionsQuotaExceeded for namespace testtrlsb. d2759061-962d-436b-980d-1b901019d569_G51 ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: ConnectionsQuotaExceeded for namespace testtrlsb. d2759061-962d-436b-980d-1b901019d569_G51Server stack trace:  
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.ThrowIfFaultMessage(Message wcfMessage) 
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.HandleMessageReceived(IAsyncResult result)Exception rethrown at[0]:  
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) 
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.DuplexCorrelationAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) 
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.b__4(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r) 
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)Exception rethrown at[1]:  
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) 
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result) 
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c__DisplayClass17.<GetAsyncSteps>b__a(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r) 
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)Exception rethrown at[2]:  
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) 
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result) 
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.b__4(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r) 
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)Exception rethrown at[3]:  
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) 
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result) 
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.EndReceiveCommand(IAsyncResult result, IEnumerable`1& messages)   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) 
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.RetryReceiveAsyncResult.TryReceiveEnd(IAsyncResult r, IEnumerable`1& messages) 
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.EndReceive(IAsyncResult result) 
 at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
 at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SubscriptionClient.ReceiveAsync()

Comment: Connections not being closed?

Comment: Are you using the Basic tier?  I think it's lower with Basic.

Answer (score 1):

We will be updating the messaging exceptions documentation very soon. This information will be there:

1. You might have a reader failing to complete messages and the messages are returning to the queue/topic when the lock expires. This can happen if the reader encounters an exception that prevents it from calling BrokeredMessage.Complete. After a message has been read ten times it will move to the Dead Letter Queue by default. This behavior is controlled by the QueueDescription.MaxDeliveryCount property and has a default value of 10. As messages pile up in the dead letter they take up space in the queue. To resolve this, read and complete the messages from the deadletter queue as you would from any other queue. QueueClient contains a method to format the deadletter path: QueueClient.FormatDeadLetterPath.
2. Another possibility is that a reader has stopped receiving messages from a queue or subscription. The way to identify this is to look at the QueueDescription.MessageCountDetails property which shows the full breakdown of the messages. If the ActiveMessageCount is high or growing, then the messages aren't being read as fast as they're being written.